# Angular 4. No puedo usar Autocomplete de PrimeNG

Tags: angular

Estoy aprendiendo a usar Angular 4, y en mi esfuerzo por aprender quiero instalar el elemento Autocomplete de [PrimeNG](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/autocomplete) y obtengo el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi proyecto es básico y tengo lo siguiente:

**autocomplete.component.html:**

```
<p-autoComplete [(ngModel)]="text" [suggestions]="results" (completeMethod)="search($event)"></p-autoComplete>
```

**autocomplete.component.ts**

```
import { AutoCompleteModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AutocompleteService } from '../../servicios/autocomplete.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-autocomplete',
  templateUrl: './autocomplete.component.html'
})
export class AutocompleteComponent implements OnInit {

   text: string;
   results: string[];

   search(event) {
      console.log( event.query )
      //   this.mylookupservice.getResults(event.query).then(data => {
      //       this.results = data;
      //   });
   }

  constructor( private _autocompleteService:AutocompleteService ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

**autocomplete.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class AutocompleteService {
   datos:any[] = [];
   urlBusqueda:string = "http://localhost:3000/consultas/";

   constructor( private http:Http ) {  }

   getDatos(termino:string){
      console.log( termino );

      // let query = `${ termino }`
      // let url = this.urlBusqueda + query;
      // return {};
      // console.log( url );
   }

}
```

Adempas, tengo referenciado el componente y el servicio en app.module.ts. ¿Qué puedo estar haciendo mal?

Answer (score 2):

Todos los imports de **primeng** los tienes que realizar en app-module, solamente los haces sobre tu componente(ademas de en app-modules) cuando tienes que declararlos y efectuar una función de los mismos.  Ej:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Message } from 'primeng/primeng';

export class Ejemplo implements OnInit {

message: Message[] = [];

constructor() { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.message = []
  this.message.push({ severity: 'info', summary: 'Buenas!', detail: 'Se cargo el componente de forma exitosa.' });    
}
```

En tu caso sería lo siguiente, dentro de app-module:

```
import { AutoCompleteModule } from 'primeng/primeng';

@NgModule({ declarations: [], import :[ AutoCompleteModule ], providers:[], bootstrap:[] })
```

---

> También puedes declarar cualquier componente-hijo que abarque tu
>   `autocomplete.component` (componente-padre), usando el decorador de angular ViewChild
>
> **HTML**
>
> ```
> <p-autoComplete #ac [(ngModel)]="text" [suggestions]="results"(completeMethod)="search($event)"></p-autoComplete>
> ```
>
> **TS**
>
> ```
>   //Child component
>   @ViewChild('ac') autocomplete;
> ```
>
> y así acceder a las propiedades, eventos y métodos del mismo

Answer (score 0):

Realizar la siguiente importación en el **app.module.ts**

```
import { AutoCompleteModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
```

y añadir AutocompleteModule en el arreglo de los Imports.

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    AutoCompleteModule
  ],
```

Funciona.